# pyttsx3 произносит каракули

Tags: python-3.x, mac, pyttsx3

У меня есть такой код:

```
# coding=utf-8
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()

tts.setProperty('rate', 200)

tts.setProperty('volume', 0.8)

tts.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.yuri.premium')

tts.say('Привет')

tts.runAndWait()
```

При запуске кода он произносит каракули, хотя в английском все нормально.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы он произносил слова нормально?

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут посмотрите примеры: [Как сделать говорящую программу на Python самостоятельно?](https://gb.ru/posts/tts_python)

В Windows голос удобно выбирать как по ID, так и по имени. В Linux проще работать с именем или языком голоса. Новый файл set_voice_and_say.py:

```
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()

voices = tts.getProperty('voices')

# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru') 

# Попробовать установить предпочтительный голос
for voice in voices:
    if voice.name == 'Aleksandr':
        tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

tts.say('Командный голос вырабатываю, товарищ генерал-полковник!')
tts.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Не помогает :-(